# How to pass a parameter when calling a Module from an Object in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, parameter-passing

I am new to VBA and have a simple question. I am having trouble passing a parameter through a Sub that is being called in an Object. If I take the parameters out of the code, it works like expected. When I put the parameters in it just stops at the `Application.Run` Code and does not even try to go into `transposeValues`, but no errors are shown. Please see below:

My Object:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Worksheets("DO NOT EDIT")
        Dim book As String
        book = "test"  
        For Each c In .Range("A1:A2").Cells

            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B" & c)) Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Application.Run "Module1.transposeValues(book)"
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
         Next
    End With
End Sub
```

My Sub where I am calling `transposeValues`:

```
Sub transposeValues(ByVal s As String)
'
' transposeValues Macro
'
    Debug.Print num
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
    Range("B1:B5000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

I tried the following lines of code as well:

1. Application.Run "Module1.transposeValues , book"
2. Application.Run Module1.transposeValues , book
3. Application.Run "Module1.transposeValues book"
4. Application.Run Module1.transposeValues book

None of these work and I tried searching online and in other stackoverflow questions and the answers don't seem to be working. Please help.

Comment: You don't need to use Application.Run here `transposeValues book` should work by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just had the syntax a little wrong. This worked:

```
Application.Run "Module1.transposeValues", book
```